# How to display differential backup date in SSMS Object Explorer Details

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssms

SQL Server Management Studio exposes the Object Explorer Details (selectable from the View menu option) and its context menu that allows adding fields to the default display.

Full and Transaction Log backup dates are optional fields. Differential backup date is not.

I could build an SSRS report to display the information. I could also create a Job that builds/exports this information.

However, I want to know if anyone has discovered a method to add Differential Backup date to the context menu as an option.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to do this that I am aware of. I use PowerShell to get this information.